# visual studio code : " sh: 1: start: not found " recieved

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

`sh: 1: start: not found` received when running simple python code. I ran some python code just today morning and it worked fine. But after I installed gTTS and pyttsx, This error started showing up. Thinking it was some VSC error, I ran the same code in pycharm, and still the same error. I did not change any settings. In the settings of pycharm and VSC, it shows pycharm 3.9 is in the correct working directory.

code : `print("Hello World")`

error: `python -u "/home/user/Desktop/CLASS_8/Studies/Computer/python/practice/A.R .py" sh: 1: start: not found`

It works when run from the terminal, but for some reason, today Visual Studio Code is not letting me run any code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*. Also make sure it's clear what's going on. What do you mean that this message is "received"? Where do you see it? Can you run the code in other ways? How about by directly at the command line?

Comment: without some actual code we are blind

Comment: oh sorry. Anyway instead of sending the big code, let me share a simple print statement.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel when I run it from another extension "Code runner" it says python is not found (expected as I  don't have python, in my OS it is called python3). But when I run from terminal, with python3 "Directory to file" it works just fine

Comment: Try uninstall one of the packages. Does it work now? What if you uninstall both?

Comment: @user202729 thanks a lot. What you asked me to do worked.